# Мне надо расположить круги так как на доске с шашками

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

У меня есть код:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('Шашки')

canvas = Canvas(root, width=700, height=700)
canvas.pack()


def square():
    y = 0
    while y < 700:
        x = 0
        while x < 700:
            canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x+88, y+88, fill='#fff', outline='#000')
            x += 88

        y += 88


def board():
    fill = '#FECD72'
    outline = '#825100'
    for i in range(0, 8):
        for j in range(0, 8):
            canvas.create_rectangle(i*88, j*88, i*88 + 88, j*88 + 88, fill=fill, outline=outline)
            fill, outline = outline, fill

        fill, outline = outline, fill


def checkers():
    fill = '#fff'
    outline = '#000'
    for check in range(0, 8, 2):
        oval =canvas.create_oval(check * 88, check * 88, check * 88 + 88, check * 88 + 88, fill=fill, outline=outline)


square()
board()
checkers()
root.mainloop()
```

И мне надо чтобы результат кружочки который получаются в результате этого кода были расположены так как на доске с шашками

Answer (score 3):

Сами расположите шашки как понравится:

```
...

def checkers():
    # 1 - белые, 2 - черные
    board = [
        [0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2],
        [2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0],
        [0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    ]

    outline = '#000'

    for i in range(8):
        for j in range(8):
            value = board[i][j]
            if value == 0:
                continue

            color = 'white' if value == 1 else 'black'

            x1, y1, x2, y2 = j * 88, i * 88, j * 88 + 88, i * 88 + 88
            canvas.create_oval(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill=color, outline=outline)

...
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]